# Only a fraction of total available RAM is used by the system

Tags: windows-10, memory, performance, amd-ryzen

I have 32Gb of RAM from 2 sticks. But only 27Gb is ever used by the sytem. That is even when the system runs into memory issue -- when my programs throw errors related to memory issues, when loading a directory of 30 files in Explorer from an SSD takes a minute, etc etc.

Both Hardware Info and Process Explorer report the remaining 5Gb of available physical memory.

The fact that no more than 27Gb RAM can be used by my system started from when I first built the system. I thought it was a mere coincidence. Back then, I ran memtest for a day and had no error. (Can't do that now. I have programs running 24/7.) There used to be stability issue somewhere in the Ryzen 3600 + X570 mobo + Win 10 combo. That was gone after one of the mobo firmware update. Other than that, I haven't had any hardware issues. But recently I've been needing the RAM space and so the RAM bottleneck is quite a problem.

What are some possible reasons behind this memory bottleneck? How do I get the system to use more of the physical RAM?

---

System specs:

- OS: Win 10
- CPU: Ryzen 3600
- GPU: GTX 1660 Ti
- Motherboard: ASUS X570 TUF Gaming PLUS Wifi
- RAM: 2 sticks of G.SKILL Trident Z Neo at 16Gb each. Model F4-3600C16D-32GTZNC
- SSD mentioned: ADATA S8200PNP at 1Tb

Incidentally, that SSD is also where pagefiles are kept. Currently Explorer reports 101Gb is available on the SSD. Pagefile limit is set to auto.

---

Example memory usage via Process Explorer when there is no apparent memory issue: (I have a hard time working the system when there is.)

[image]

Comment: I see a charge of more like virtual 69 GB used, where Windows managed to free about 8 GB of real RAM for its operation. Where do you see 27 GB?

Comment: @harrymc: First, 27 Gb is not the current state. 27Gb is the observed ceiling. When 27 Gb is hit, I do encounter memory issues. User input has a lagged response, for example. I cannot afford inducing memory issues wantonly because I have programs running 24/7. Hence I attached a screenshot when RAM used is below that ceiling. I explained this reason in the question. Given that context, please note that used physical + available physical = ram limit.

Comment: Your commit charge is extremely large. You have a program that is leaking memory. // Also note that low memory (as in "out of memory" errors) is _exclusively_ related to commit charge, not to physical memory usage.

Comment: @DanielB: Blame Chrome. Let's accept that as the memory need. Memory need doesn't explain the problem at hand though.

Comment: @DanielB: I don't receive "out of memory" errors from Win 10. I encounter memory related issues in my programs and normal typical daily use.

Comment: No, this is not normal. Not even remotely. You need to investigate. It’s easy, too, because Commit Charge is its own column in Task Manager (“Commit size”) or Process Explorer (“Private Bytes”).

Comment: @DanielB: Right at this moment, Explorer for example asks for 27Gb+ of memory and uses <5Gb. I think it's always been like that.

Comment: @DanielB: Btw, what can I do to leaky programs that I can't modify myself?

Comment: You don't need to do anything - Windows will swap out unused memory to make room for used one. You should perhaps investigate whether the leak is caused by an extension in the browser.

Comment: @harrymc: I would like Windows to start using the remaining physical memory though. 5Gb out of 32Gb is rather steep.

Comment: It's "using" 69GB right now, 96 peak. I'm not sure where your 27 comes from, but you're way, waaay past that

Comment: Windows needs some free space, because some operations cannot wait for swap. It will never use 100%.

Comment: @Tetsujin: I believe I did make it clear that 27 is used physical memory. You clearly know "committed" memory is not actually always needed. Depending on the software, only a fraction may be.

Comment: @harrymc: I expected it does. But is this what you experience? 5Gb reserved away? That's keeping in mind that other system processes do still use the remaining 27Gb according to itself, which is where Process Explorer get the info from. Is that 5Gb actually being used?

Answer (score 1):

You have incredibly high commit charge. That means one of two things:

- You are trying to run stuff that needs more RAM than you have (4 times as much)
- You have software that is leaking memory

Please do not accept ~95 GiB of commit charge as normal. It is not, not with merely 32 GiB of physical RAM.

---

You indicate in your comments that Windows Explorer has a commit size of over 27 GiB. This is not normal and could totally be the problem. Of course, it’s not Explorer itself but rather a so-called shell extension. You can use [ShellExView](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html) to investigate which shell extensions you have. It can also disable shell extensions.

So what you want to do is:

Try and disable different shell extensions, preferably keeping the Microsoft ones enabled at all times. I think you need to restart Explorer (for example from Task Manager) for the changes to take effect. Once you have found the culprit, you can remove it permanently.

Just for some reference: On my system, which has the following third-party shell extensions, Explorer is using under 100 MiB of memory:

- 7-Zip (2 exts)
- Diff Ext
- Git Extensions
- HashCheck
- Macrium Reflect (5 exts)
- Notepad++
- NVIDIA graphics drivers (4 exts)
- Sumatra PDF (2 exts)

---

When an application is asking for memory, it doesn’t ask for physical memory but rather “commit charge”. The maximum amount of available “commit charge” is physical memory (fixed amount obviously) + page file (usually dynamic size). Once Windows has grown the page file to the acceptable limit (whatever that is), programs asking for memory will get out-of-memory errors. Usually, Windows also displays a warning dialog about how memory is running low.

When too many programs make too many large memory reservations but don’t use it, you will run out of memory, even if your physical RAM still isn’t entirely used. It still is *reserved*. This is most likely what you are seeing.

Comment: I appreciate the answer. I'll rely on your advice when I deal with the large memory commit issue. But that's separate from the issue I have. I need to know that either Windows has solid reasons to reserve those 5Gb of RAm and is actively using it despite of not appearing so, or that it starts actually using it. I am not receiving out of memory errors. I am observing issues of excessive amount of memory swaps slowing down the system when 27Gb RAM is used. And then, more importantly, either that or somewhere as data is paged/fetched/stored, my programs throw errors that are cause of concerns

Comment: in terms of data integrity. Having large requested memory but never needing it is *not* memory leaking. Not needing the data or having lost track of them yet still causing the system to maintain the data in memory is leaking. You can't really conclude that high commit means memory leaking. That would be potentially runaway RAM usage that (much more) severely restrict the memory head room I am already not having. And that would not appear only as high commit. It would appear as ever growing private set.

Comment: In addition, I don't have issue with total private set exceeding physical RAM. Win 10 seems to do a good job of determining what is actively running, what is receiving user input etc. And put most of those data on harddrive while preserving performance for the more active programs. I don't need performance for the remaining programs. I only experience problem when the invisible 27Gb ceiling is reached.